# Fresh cookiecutter django project shows "Invalid syntax" at environ.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I started my first project with cookiecutter using the cookiecutter-django template.

When I tried to start it from PyCharm using the virtualenv, it gave me an error in a lib file: environ.py, telling me this:

```
  File "/home/madtyn/venvs/nana/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ.py", line 114
    raise ValueError, "No frame marked with %s." % fname
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

After searching, I consulted somebody and I was recommended another way. I tried, as they told me, to make a new venv,

```
python3 -m venv /home/madtyn/venvs/name
```

activate it

```
source /home/madtyn/venvs/name/bin/activate
```

and run the server from command line but the same thing seems to happen.

I don't think I did anything wrong. These are my specifications:

- Kubuntu (64bit arch)
- Python 3.6.8 (both the venv and the main one)
- cookiecutter 1.6.0 (installed through pip3)
- PyCharm 2019.2.2

Comment: Please show exactly what you typed to set up your venv and install the libraries, plus the *full* traceback. Somehow you have installed a module - environ.py - that is not compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Did you actually install the requirements in your virtualenv? After source you should do `pip install -r requirements/local.txt`.

Comment: Well, that made a difference. Now is complaining about the database, so you can answer that and I will consider it as the solution and the problem to be solved.

Thank you

Comment: @madtyn The full error would be useful in order to help you on this matter :)

Comment: @frankie567 If you mean about the new database error, it is a normal error, almost an expected error and I knew about it and how to solve it. I consider the question answered and I'm accepting your answer as soon as you post it down here. The solution was to install those requirements. My bad.

Comment: @madtyn Oh, ok, sorry, I misunderstood your comment :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install the Python dependencies after having activated your virtual environment:

```sh
pip install -r requirements/local.txt
```

Answer (score 14):

if you need environ for Django use

```
pip install django-environ
```

so this error will go out